# I'm looking for a series of books the sisters of something I think

Tags: story-identification

The book is about a group of women called "the sisters of _____" they live on a planet with some sort of communication array that they believe their gods use to communicate with them.

I began reading it in high school back in 2000 and not only can't find them but can't recall who wrote them or the actual title; all I can recall is something about the sisters of *blank*.

I can't recall if the sisters was in the title but it has nothing to do with Earth. They're on an alien planet and are accidentally found by an Earth man who explains the true situation to them. He eventually either lands and meets them, or attempts to land there. It's from the early 2000s and I think a woman wrote the books. I recall there being three of them.

Comment: Do any of [these](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=the+sisters+of&type=Fiction+Titles) ring a bell?